# Difference between commits exists but git log doesn't show changes

Tags: git

I have some curious situation and not undestand it.

When I use `git log -p -<n>` I don't see changes what exists in file, but If I try `git diff <prev>..<next> <file>` difference exists and shown. Why can it be?

Git diff returns blob numbers `index cd785c4..967453b 100644`, what I can do with that?

Can that information be helpful for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I use `git log -p -<n>` I don't see changes what exists in file, but If I try `git diff <prev>..<next> <file>` difference exists and shown. Why can it be?

This means the commit in question is a *merge commit*, i.e., a commit with at least two parent IDs.  When `git log -p` or `git show` is showing a merge, their default is to use git's *combined diff* format.

The precise details of combined diffs are in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) under the [combined diff format](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format) section, but I'll quote from the ["diff format for merges" section](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html#_diff_format_for_merges):

> Note that *combined diff* lists only files which were **modified from all parents**.

(boldface mine).  Suppose, for instance, that you merge branch `feature` into branch `develop`, and that in `develop`, file `README` says, in part:

```
There will be a feature X soon.
```

Suppose that in `feature`, `README` says:

```
Feature X is now supported.
```

When you merge `feature` into `develop`, the file `README` picks up the change—but the resulting `README` exactly matches the version in `develop`.

If you now `git show` the merge commit (or it comes up in `git log -p`), the *combined diff* compares `README` in the merge against `README` in the *first* parent (it's different, it has the "now supported" text when `develop` didn't before), then compares `README` in the merge against `README` in the *second* parent.  The second comparison shows no change since the merge picked up the `feature` version, so the combined diff **omits file `README`**.

When you find the first parent ID of the merge, i.e., the commit that was the tip of `develop` before the merge, and `git diff` that commit against the merge commit, you get a regular (non-combined) diff, and since `README` picked up the change, you see the change.

Note that you can use the `-m` option to tell things that show merges (`git log` and `git show`, for instance) to display one diff against each parent, rather than a single combined diff.  (For typical two-parent merges, this shows two diffs against the one commit.  Internally, these commands generate a fake extra commit to do this.  You should not have to know about the internal-only fake commit, but it leaks out in some cases.)

---

> Git diff returns blob numbers `index cd785c4..967453b 100644`, what I can do with that?

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20214732/1256452).