# Git seems to have not applied a diff to my sandbox that it pulled from master

Tags: git

I have a file in my sandbox that doesn't contain the last change committed to git. When I pulled the change to this file from master to this sandbox it doesn't seem to have been applied to the file in the sandbox. How do I figure out what went wrong? How do I fix the file?

This is the output of `git status`:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

This is the output of `git log -p`:

```
commit 93d5a36d9e11a2b61bf0e05cddcc7a07339177b3
Merge: fd1a7e7 ac18f6a
Author: me <me@me.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 25 19:43:48 2016 -0400

    Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master'

commit ac18f6ab799f0d613866fa2992d12240399e0341
Author: me <me@me.com>
Date:   Fri Mar 25 18:58:03 2016 -0400

    change

diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index c31f440..51c0628 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -35,6 +35,93 @@
+this content is missing from the file in the sandbox
```

Comment: You don't say why you believe "[the change] doesn't seem to have been applied to the file in the sandbox".  Your git output doesn't indicate that the change is not applied: it shows that there's a patch in one of the two parent commits of the merge (specifically `ac18f6a...`), and cuts off at that point, showing nothing about the other parent of the merge (`fd1a7e7...`).  You won't see anything in the `p` section for the merge itself unless you add `-m` to your `git log` command.

Comment: @torek Thank you for looking. I added `-m` and can see that the merge removed the lines added by the second commit. Maybe there was a conflict that was resolved badly? The merge commit was done by doing a pull from within XCode and XCode didn't tell me about the conflict.

Comment: Ah, no, it's because you're expecting something git on-purpose doesn't do by default.  This is actually a duplicate, well, sort of.  Let me find my other answer on the other question...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36159040/1256452 (well, sort of, as noted).  As for why the line is removed, that's a bit more mysterious.  Perhaps the merge was done with `--ours`?  (Note: I haven't used Xcode and don't know how it invokes various git commands.)